# How do i make a discord.py bot do an action only when a certain role sends a message?

Tags: python, discord

I need to make a bot that sends a message whenever a certain role just sends a message, my question is if thats even possible to do since all i've seen discord bots do is send messages once a command is triggered so im curious if that is even possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to trigger a command only if a user with certain roles tries to do so.

If it is a command then you use `@app_commands.checks.has_role` or `@app_commands.checks.has_any_roles`
Example:

```py
@client.command
@app_commands.checks.has_role("name")
async def my_command(ctx):
    # do something

@client.command
@app_commands.has_any_role("role1","foo",11132312313213)
async def my_command1(ctx):
    #do something
```

You can also check for certain role in `on_message` by using `discord.Member.get_role()`

Example:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.get_role(role_id):
        #do something
```

Docs refrence:

- [`@app_commands.check.has_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.app_commands.checks.has_role)
- [`@app_commands.check_has_any_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.app_commands.checks.has_any_role)
- [`discord.Member.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Member.get_role)

Comment: Good to hear that! You can set this answer as accepted answer, so that it helps other to find solution to similar problem.